# BODMAS, Java. Simple Math that won't Add Up

Tags: java, loops, math, addition

Hello can't figure out why I can't get right result for startE

just a simple program, to illustrate the problem.

"NUMBER CLASS"

```
public class Number {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grow big = new Grow();
        big.growing();
    }}
```

"GROW CLASS"

```
public class Grow {
    private int startE = 50000 / 1 / 2;
    private int startC = 50000 / 1 / 3;

    public void growing() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            startE = startE + (((50000 * (13 / 20)) - (50000 * (1 / 2))) / 200);
            startC = startC + ((50000 / 1 / 2 - 50000 / 1 / 3) / 75);

            System.out.println(startE);
            System.out.println(startC);

        }
    }}
```

You will see that 'startC' does as expected, however I am getting no joy with 'startE'
If you can help that would be great

What it prints out on console.

```
25000
25000
25000
25000
25000 etc
```

Comment: What are you getting? Your `no joy` is very vague. We don't know what gives you joy.

Comment: Read up about integer division.

Comment: ZouZou I am pretty sure my equation is correct, it is part of a much more complicated program, that has many simpler equations. It is just this one that I have now spent a few hours trying to solve, and simply can't. Hence that is why I attempted to reap the benefits of this community. For now and again we all need help.

Comment: @user3459475 I think ZouZou was referring to integer division in Java. See my answer below it explains why the value for `startE` doesn't change

Comment: @user3459475 Yes I was speaking about integer division in Java (and for most of programming languages). Not about your mathematical operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because of how integer division works in Java:

```
startE = startE + (((50000 * (13 / 20)) - (50000 * (1 / 2))) / 200);
```

When you do `13/20` above, it returns `0` because all the values following the decimal point are discarded in `int`s. This is equivalent of the `floor` in math. When you multiply `50000` with `0`, you get a `0`. Same thing with `1/2`. It becomes `0` and `0` multiplied by anything is `0`.

Your `startE` value starts at `25000`. When you add `0` to `25000` you get `25000`. That is the reason you keep seeing `25000` in the loop.

Comment: THANKS...you are spot on..the solution as it stands was                 "startE = startE + (((50000 * 13 / 20) - (50000 * 1 / 2)) / 200);"